# Why do guides always say to download the RPM to disk?

Tags: installation, rpm

Every installation guide I've ever seen which requires an RPM install starts with the instruction "download the repo", usually accompanied by a `wget`, and then, separately, says to `rpm -i` or `rpm -U` the downloaded file.

Except I've noticed `rpm` supports remote URI schemes (at least, it supports FTP, HTTP and HTTPS). Clearly, to install a remote repo, `rpm` must already download the file (maybe not to disk, but I'd be surprised if it didn't). So, presumably, the issue isn't that `rpm` can't just install the thing given a link.

### My Question

Besides the utility of having an audit trail, the convenience that comes with being able to do the install offline, and the fact that a failure on install wouldn't require a redownload of the RPM, are there any good reasons to install from the local drive? Does `rpm` treat local files differently?

**-- Also, just in case anyone happens to know --**

If the files are downloaded to disk (which, again, would be the overwhelmingly sanest thing to do), are they removed at program termination, or do they persist? And if they *do* persist... where?

Answer (score 2):

Downloading rpm file first can be a huge time saver, not for mere installation, but for inspection of rpm package before installing. People can check out what they are trying to install (`rpm -qlpv`, `rpm -qp --scripts` and so on), if the rpm is compatible with distro (`rpm -qpi`), etc. The whole file will need to be fetched over and over if the direct URL link is used.